# Azure functions - how do I get application insights to NOT log availability test outcome

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have an azure function which exposes an endpoint that I use for checking the availability.

Application insights logs the results of this availability test every time it does a check.

I would like to have the availability tests, but I don't want my application insights    to show these logs. How can I exclude these availability tests from my application insights?

Better still - I would like AI to actually just log the failures - how could I go about this?

I know about ITelemetryProcessor - and this works for ASP.Net Core apps - but for azure functions what is the approach?

This is a .Net 3.1 azure function app

Comment: This might be due to my lack of knowledge but do you not log based on your log.Information or so on function? kind of like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-log-levels)

Comment: Do you want to exclude them at query time? Or do you want not to ingest them?

Comment: When you add an availability test, it pings your endpoint at fixed intervals and this generates the logs in application insights. 

I want the availability tests but not the logs. I don't want any of the logs (due to cost)

Comment: You can define the `LogLevel` at your function level in host.json, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json).  for instance `"namespace.MyAvailabilityFunction"` : "none"

Answer (score 0):

I know about ITelemetryProcessor - and this works for ASP.Net Core

> apps - but for azure functions what is the approach?

You can use Monitor availability with URL ping tests.

Setting up

1. From the Monitoring section, select Diagnostic settings and then add Diagnostic settings.
   [image]
2. Under Diagnostics Settings, select category details and log, choose functionApplogs.
   [image]
3. Here you can run a query for a specific result.
   [image]

For more information read these Microsoft documents on [Monitor availability with URL ping tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability)

another way you can see in availability under Investigate.
[image]

and you can also [Create and run custom availability tests using Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/availability-azure-functions) by Microsoft Documents.